# Need tips to create a sublime text plugin for Git

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm already familiar with the basics of sublime plugins and created a few simple ones. But now I would like to write a plugin which uses Git, and I'm not know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

Start reading/studing the current git's plugins code for `Sublime Text`:

1. https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter
2. https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git